# For loop time update(H:i) with 10 minutes in php

Tags: php, time

I am trying to update time in for loop in php and i am getting unexpected results.

I have tried using while loop still same results. Dont know where its going wrong.

```
$time = strtotime(date('H:i'));
$trounds= 15;
for($j = 1; $j<= $trounds ; $j++){
    echo $time += date("H:i:s", strtotime("+10 minutes", $time));
    echo date('H:i:s',$time);
    echo '</br>';
   }
```

Suppose if the time is 12:00 i need output like 
12:10
12:20
12:30
and so on.

Comment: What if the time is 12:03? Can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: If the current time is 13:00 i want resullts as(+10 minutes)
13:10
13:20
13:30
13:40 and so on.. if its 12:03 then 12:13, 12:23,12:33 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't need `date()` and `strtotime()` twice , Try like below

```
$time = strtotime(date('4:i'));
$trounds= 15;
for($j = 1; $j<= $trounds ; $j++){
    echo $time += 10*60;
      echo ' : '.date('H:i:s',$time);
    echo "\n";
   }
```

[Live Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cfc53092b8841113ab8e64d0a8ff1a1e99f4b8b5)

Output :

```
1563017220 : 04:27:00
1563017820 : 04:37:00
1563018420 : 04:47:00
1563019020 : 04:57:00
1563019620 : 05:07:00
1563020220 : 05:17:00
1563020820 : 05:27:00
1563021420 : 05:37:00
1563022020 : 05:47:00
1563022620 : 05:57:00
1563023220 : 06:07:00
1563023820 : 06:17:00
1563024420 : 06:27:00
1563025020 : 06:37:00
1563025620 : 06:47:00
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$date = new DateTime();
echo "Current Date Time: "; print_r($date); echo "</br>";
$trounds= 15;
for($j = 0; $j< $trounds ; $j++){
  $date->modify("+10 minutes");
  print_r($date->format('H:i')); echo '</br>';
}

exit;
```

Use **PHP DateTime Class** For Better Usage and Flexibility. You can read and learn more about from PHP official docs : [PHP DateTime Class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). You can make use of various other methods that are provided by the DateTime Class.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the incorrect values in your `$time` after the just after the for loop which is making it wrong

```
$time = strtotime(date('H:i'));
$trounds= 15;
for($j = 1; $j<= $trounds ; $j++){
    echo $time = strtotime("+10 minutes", $time); //echo $time += date("H:i:s", strtotime("+10 minutes", $time));
    echo date('H:i:s',$time);
    echo '</br>';
}
```

You're adding the string format ("H:i:s") value into the float value.. Check the above code you just need to assign the strtotime value and it will do rest.